# How can I access a HTML element via NodeJS without the need for third party libraries

Tags: node.js, database, database-connection, getelementbyid

So the issue is that I am trying to get a html element and change the innerHTML of it.

Before anything else I will first say that my app requires to be connected to a database and also needs to perform all four CRUD operations, when I tried connecting to the database and ran it through the cmd (When HTML wasn't involved yet) it worked. When I put it on a server (localhost 3000) it also worked, but the issue is that I have a paragraph in my HTML and I want it to display "Successfully connected to the database" but this is where the issue starts, I can't access the DOM element, I tried to access it with a few ways, here is my code :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=3000; 

fs.readFile('./conn.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;    

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
        this.html = html;
    }).listen(PORT);
});
```

So I first tried doing `document.getElementById(...)` and it didn't work, which is understandable, but then I tried substituting the document with html and response and still didn't work, and now I am confused on what I should do.

**Can Someone Please Give Me A Way I Can Solve This Problem ?**

Answer (score 0):

[cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) will let you access html content like a web browser document.

```
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

const $ = cheerio.load(html)
$('#message').text(`Successfully connected to the database`)
```

But you may find it easier to use a "template" or "view" system if you are building a web app.

[Fastify](https://github.com/fastify/point-of-view)/[Koa](https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views#readme)/[Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) all support building HTML responses from templates.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="message" class="message">
    {{ my_message }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then there's [Nuxt](https://nuxt.com/docs) (Vue), [Sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) (Svelte) and [Next](https://nextjs.org/) (React) which support building more interactive pages from Javscript components.

```
<script setup>
const my_message = `Successfully connected to the database`
</script>

<template>
  <div id="message" class="message">
    {{ my_message }}!
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I asked ChatGPT about this and it said that it is advisable to use FetchAPI if you have already written the HTML code and you don't want to change everything to make it work with Node. Can you please tell what you say about this?